# "Unsupported operation: toImage is not supported on the Web" -- I get this Error while take screenshot in my flutter web using "Screenshot" plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to capture a screenshot of a specific container widget on the Flutter web using the **[Screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)** plugin.

However, when I attempt to take the screenshot, I encounter an error stating,
**unsupported operation: toimage is not supported on the web**

My Flutter version is:3.19.3

My Dart sdk version is:3.3.1

I hope someone can assist me in resolving this issue. Thank you.

I want take screenshots from my screen particular widget

i will attach my code snippet below

//Controller initialization

ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

//ScreenShot Widget

Column(
children:[
Screenshot( controller: screenshotController, child: Container( color: Colors.red, height: 200, width: 200, ), ),

//Button

ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () { screenshotController .capture(delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 10)) .then((capturedImage) async { }).catchError((onError) { }); }, )
]))

Comment: Please share your code for more references.

Comment: ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
  Screenshot(
              controller: screenshotController,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
              ),
            )
 onPressed: () {
                  screenshotController
                      .capture(delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 10))
                      .then((capturedImage) async {
                  
                  }).catchError((onError) {
                  });
                },

Comment: Please Add your widget and code in description!

Comment: [edit] your post to add the necessary code. Comments are temporary